# Including leading whitespace in lstinline inside a cell

Tags: tables, listings

Here is a MWE:

```
% !TEX program = xelatex

\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\lstset{
    basicstyle=\fontsize{9}{11}\ttfamily,
}

\begin{document}

\lstinline{Without leading space}
\lstinline{    With leading space}

\begin{tabular}{ l }
    \midrule
    \makecell[cl]{{\lstinline!First!} \\ {\lstinline!    Second!}} \\
    \midrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

The output is:

[image]

I'm trying to get "second" indented 4 characters in from "First". Leading whitespace is respected outside the table cell, but not inside it.

Any ideas how to fix?

Answer (score 3):

You run into problems if you put `\lstinline` inside the argument of another command (here: `\makecell`) as it then no longer do its catcode magic -- the lost spaces is one of them, other are with comment chars and commands.  It is much safer to put the verbatim directly inside the cell:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\lstset{
    basicstyle=\fontsize{9}{11}\ttfamily,
}

\begin{document}

\lstinline{Without leading space}

\lstinline{    With leading space}

\textbf{\lstinline{    With lost leading space}}

\begin{tabular}{ l }
    \midrule
    \lstinline!First!\\
    \lstinline!    Second!\\
    \midrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can put the `lstinline` in a minipage. Disadvantages: I'm not sure how to use this together with `makecell`, and you have to set the minipage size manually. Advantage: it works.

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{listings}
%\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\lstset{
    basicstyle=\fontsize{9}{11}\ttfamily,
}

\begin{document}

\lstinline{Without leading space}

\lstinline{    With leading space}

\begin{tabular}{l}
    \midrule
    \begin{minipage}[t][22pt][t]{0.25\textwidth}\lstinline!First!\\\lstinline!    Second! \end{minipage} \\
    \midrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]